# java method statement begins with: 'return new' (Confusion regarding anonymous classes)

Tags: java, return, new-operator, anonymous-class

Why does the method begin with 'return new' ?

```
public Iterator<T> iterator() {  
    return new Iterator<T>() {  
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It's same as the Iterator variable was assigned with a 'new' and later returned.

Comment: You seem to be thinking of it as return new (....).  It's actually return (new ...);

Comment: Sure, but why not have this return statement inside the method?

Comment: ...It is inside the method.  What do you think the alternative is?

Comment: What you're seeing here is an anonymous inner class, I suspect that's the cause of the confusion.

Comment: Who downvoted this? This is a perfectly reasonable question.

Answer (score 4):

This creates an instance of the class (in fact it creates a *subclass* of the class, as @biziclop has nitpicked) and returns it. This is usually used in 'Factory' kind of classes, along these lines:

```
public static Button createButton(int x, int y, String label){
     return new Button(x,y,label){
         void onClick(){
          ...
         }
     }
}

/* .... */
Button b = Toolkit.createButton(20,20,"Hello!");
```

Comment: I know it's nitpicking, but it creates **a subclass** of the class, then an instance of that and returns it. The distinction is important because you can (and indeed quite often will) do this with abstract classes and interfaces. (In the latter case it creates an implementation, but that's nitpicking++.)

Comment: @biziclop lol, but thanks for the nitpicking. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The method `iterator()` returns a `Iterator<T>` type, so the method should have a `return` statement followed by a an object of type `Iterator<T>`.

```
new Iterator<T>() {  
    ...
}
```

This is anonymous class where you can instantiate an instance of interface with implementing all the abstract methods inside that anonymous class. Read more about [Anonymous classes](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/anonymousclasses.html).

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is a method, `public Iterator<T> iterator()`, which is returning a new anonymous inner class instance, not a method. The confusion is understandable if you've never seen anonymous inner classes before.

[Here's a little info on anonymous classes in Java.](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/swing/anonymous_inner_classes.shtml)